# Is my answer to the following integral $\int \frac{x-1}{(x-2)(x^2-2x+2)^2} dx$ correct?

Tags: integration

The answer that I have found is: $$\frac 1 4 \ln|x-2|-\frac 3 8 \ln|x^2-2x+2|+\frac 1 4 \arctan(x-1)+C.$$

Wolframalpha is saying that the answer is: $$\frac 1 8 \Big(\frac{2x}{x^2 - 2 x + 2} - \ln|x^2 - 2 x + 2| + 2 \ln|x - 2|\Big)+C,$$

whereas my textbook says the answer should be: $$\frac 1 8 \ln|\frac{(x-2)^2}{x^2-2x+2}|+\frac{x-1}{4x^2-8x+8} + C.$$

Of these three, my answer seems to be the most exotic, involving $\arctan$, however I've double checked my work and have found no mistake. I don't know how to get to the other two solutions.

Comment: @CYAries I will post my answer in just a minute.

Comment: Did you do partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: Show your steps @J.Doe

Comment: @CYAries here is my work (sorry for the hand writing): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3qICUp7nCyHZlBkenNFWm9Qa2Y1WVJpSm5Ub1VlVVMtUFdv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @JohnColtraneisJC Yes, you can see here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3qICUp7nCyHZlBkenNFWm9Qa2Y1WVJpSm5Ub1VlVVMtUFdv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @nmasanta Here you go: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3qICUp7nCyHZlBkenNFWm9Qa2Y1WVJpSm5Ub1VlVVMtUFdv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Wolfram is correct (you can differentiate to check it).  The textbook looks like Wolfram's answer (with a typo).

Comment: You forgot the square (in the denominator) in the evaluation of $I_3$.

Comment: @CYAries That's embarrassing, but thank you for pointing out my mistake. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks once again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the posted answers (other than *Wolfram*) are wrong.

The correct answer is

$$\frac 1 8 \ln\frac{(x-2)^2}{|x^2-2x+2|}+\frac{x}{4x^2-8x+8} + \textrm{const.}$$

This can be checked by differentiating.  You should get back the original integrand.

Comment: This is **exactly** the same as Wolfram's answer...

Comment: @mjw No, it doesn't. Read again.

Comment: Oh, you are right.  There is a typo above.

Comment: Updated my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but then you added nothing new. Perhaps a slick way to check Wolfram's answer is correct and not directly by differentiating, which seems to be akward...?

Comment: There were three answers given.  I (and Dr. Graubner) both identified the correct answer.  Not saying this is fantastic, but hopefully helpful.  Thanks again for the comments@!

Answer (score 2):

i got $$\frac{\ln|x-2|}{4}+\frac{x}{4(x^2-2x+2)}-\frac{\ln(x^2-2x+2)}{8}+C$$
Differentiating this with respect to $x$:
$$\frac{1}{4(x-2)}+\frac{1}{4x^2-8x+8}-\frac{x(8x-8)}{(4x^2-8x+8)^2}+\frac{2x-2}{8(x^2-2x+2)}$$
Writing the given integral as $$\int\frac{x-1}{(x-2)((x-1)^2+1)}dx$$
and substituting $$t=x-1$$ we get
$$\int\frac{t}{(t-1)(t^2+1)^2}dt$$

Comment: This is the same as Wolfram's...

Comment: Na bravo, but i have used pencil and paper

Comment: So what? The Op doesn't need you to prove your skills in solving partial fractions integrals, but rather a way to check this or that answer is corrects, in a more or less easy way (differentiating that looks nasty...but that's always a way)

Comment: I like your comments!

Comment: Here differentiating is a way!  Nice point!

Comment: I like these comments too.  I am going to upvote (up-triangle) them!

Comment: Ok, i will do it!